# How to access specific tr and td from a tbody without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm trying to access the first `tr` and from it the second and third `td` element. However, I want to achieve this without the usage of jQuery or any other library. I already tried accessing it by using `.childNodes[1]` or by trying to treat it as an array. I want to know how to do this in general so I can apply it for other tables aswell (in case I want to access a different `tr`)

The `tbody`:

```
<tbody>
  <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td>0</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`HTMLTableElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) element contains a [`rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows) property and a [`HtmlTableRowElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement) has a `cells` property. Both are collections.

Alternatively you can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to retrieve (an array of) cells within the first row and subsequently retrieve the last two of those.

You can also get the targeted cells using one css query (last alternative).

```js
const firstRow = document.querySelector(`table tbody`).rows[0];
console.log(firstRow);
const secondTdOfFirstRow = firstRow.cells[1];
console.log(secondTdOfFirstRow);

// alternative
const firstRowLastTwoCells = [...document
  .querySelectorAll(`table tbody tr:nth-child(1) td`)].slice(-2);
console.log(firstRowLastTwoCells);

// another alternative
const firstRowLastTwoCellsInOneGo = document
  .querySelectorAll(`table tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:not(:first-child)`);
console.log([...firstRowLastTwoCellsInOneGo])
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td>0</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Also see the documentation for [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)